# RabbitMQ queue timeout with a consumer

Tags: rabbitmq

I'm looking for a way to make a queue expire even if there's an active consumer listening. From this site https://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html it says

> Unused means the queue has no consumers, the queue has not been
>   redeclared, and basic.get has not been invoked for a duration of at
>   least the expiration period.

I want all of those things, but I want the queue to go away even if there's a consumer listening. Is that possible?

Comment: I agree with the answer provided by @Derick Bailey but I'm just curious - why would you need this? What is the use case?

Comment: @cantSleepNow I have an RPC producer that creates a private queue per message and then listens on it. But the workers might not ever respond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is that possible?

not directly within RabbitMQ.

as long as a consumer is connected to the queue, listening for messages, the queue will stay alive.

you could have some code delete the queue after a period of time, though. that would be about your only option.